# Calculate lengths by mode in network analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I have a multi-modal network (Rail, Roads and River/Ocean) for network analyst.  I am calculating travel costs along the multi-modal network.  I get a total length field, but is there anyway to get a total length by each mode for each route?  I have thousands or routes so don't really want to try selecting them all out.  Any ideas?

Comment: What software are you using? Is this an ArcGIS product?

Comment: Yes I am using ArcGIS

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "Copy Traversed Source Features" GP tool? It will, as per doc:

> Creates two feature classes and a table, which together contain information about the edges, junctions, and turns that are traversed while solving a network analysis layer.

The `Edges` table has SourceName and accumulation values ... this might be the info you are looking for.